# field collections and blocks

Tags: views, blocks, entities

I have a number of content Types (Basic Pages) and a region (right sidebar)

What I'm looking to do, is display a particular fields content in this block depending on what page I'm on.

I know I could do this for a block for each page, but I have over 200 pages, and doing this for all of them would be time consuming.

I have created a field collection named 'rightcol' which is a text field.

So ideally, what i need is when I'm on a particular page, in the right-hand region, that pages 'rightcol' content will display.

Am I correct in thinking I'd need to create a view for this?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are correct. You should be able to create a view block, set the field to be "rightcol" and then use contextual filters (under advanced features) to filter what is in the view depending on URL.

Comment: When creating the view am I selecting to Show 'field collection item' ?

Comment: I don't have the the field collection module installed, but I believe that is correct. Also check this out http://drupal.org/project/field_collection_views

Comment: Ok, i have done the following: Created a View. Set `Show` to 'Field collection item' and created a block with a `Display format` of 'Unformatted list' of 'fields'. I've then added a `contextual filter` to filter by 'rightcol' but it doesn't return anything. Am i doing this right?